# When the image of operator be subset of $l_p$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $f:l_{\infty} \rightarrow l_{\infty}$ defined by $f(x_1,x_2,...)=(x_1,\frac{1}{2}x_2,...,\frac{1}{2}x_n,...)$. Then we need to (1) prove that $f$ is continuous operator and (2) find $p\geq 1$ such that $Im(f) \subset l_p$.

My attempt:
(1) I proved that $f$ is bounded, namely, $||f(x)||_{\infty} \leq ||x||_{\infty}$, and so it continuous

(2) We need to find all $p\geq 1$ such that: every $x \in l_{\infty}$ we have $f(x) \in l_p$, i.e. $||f(x)||_p < \infty$, i.e. $|x_1|^p +\sum_{n \geq 2} |\frac{1}{2}x_n|^p < \infty$.
Taking $x=(1,1,...) \in l_{\infty}$ we have $|1|^p +\sum_{n \geq 2} |\frac{1}{2}|^p < \infty$ which is a contradiction, so can we say there is no such $p$ exists.

Comment: Your $f$ is bijective, so its image is always $\ell^\infty$; this sounds like a typo.  Most likely the second $1/2$ was $1/n$?

Comment: @MartinArgerami so $im(f)=l_{\infty} \subset l_p$ for all $p \geq 1$. right?

Comment: No inclusion. That's why it's very likely that you have a typo.

Comment: For any $1 \leq p < q \leq \infty$ you have $\ell^p \subsetneq \ell^q$.